# Ensuring previewed still-frame of video is correct in PowerPoint

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I'm putting together a PowerPoint 2007 presentation and need to include a video, which is animated vector graphics that I'm producing by making lots of PNG files and then using FFmpeg to compile them into a video.

So far I've tried .mp4 and .avi formats. The video in .mp4 looks much better than .avi, and both videos display properly, but the preview still frame that is shown before the video starts is messed up.

In .mp4 I just get a black frame, which sucks. In .avi, I get the first frame on initial display, but after the video completes, it shows a black frame.

Is there any way to get it to always display the first frame when the video is not being played?

Comment: `ffmpeg -i inputfile%03d.png outputfile.mp4` or `.avi` or whatever

Comment: Tags don't show up in the "Related" and "Linked" sidebars, and until they do I will continue putting context hints in the title. (And for the record, the meta.SO question doesn't say "Tags don't go into the title", it's a discussion about whether they should do so.)

Comment: Didn't want to start a discussion, but as you can see, the community clearly agrees they shouldn't – that's what I meant by linking to the question and the reason I edited the title.

Comment: Anyway, wouldn't using the AVI video be the more ideal solution? The reason it lacks quality is probably due to the default choices FFmpeg makes when converting them, thus reducing the bitrate or choosing a worse video codec. By the way: PowerPoint 2011 (the only version I can test) *does* preview everything correctly, but stops at the last frame of the video.

Comment: AVI shows the 1st frame initially, but after you play it once, it goes to a black frame. (I've read that Powerpoint 2010 (2011? 2010?) handles video much better, but our corporate software is still on 2007.)